How to use Flake8 as linter for Jupyter notebook in vscode?
I have installed the Flask8 plugin in Vscode from the extension library.
I want the linter to work in Jupyter notebook for file extension .ipynb.

I tried ctrl + shift + p to change linter. I cannot find Flake8.
I have installed pylint however that does not work in Jupyter notebook, is there a way to enable it for .ipynb.

Jupyter use black as the Linter instead of flake8.
Read this issue for more detials.


Black formats the code, but how to enable it as a linter

@Master Install the black formatter in VSCode extension store and it'll set black as linter.
